# decode windows 1256 to utf-8 in android

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8

I have a string which is decoded by windows-1256 like this

> A0C8E5CFC7CF2DC7DDDEE5ED

I want to encode that to UTF-8 in android.
I tried to encode like this

```
String input = "A0C8E5CFC7CF2DC7DDDEE5ED";
    try {
        String message = new String(input.getBytes(), "windows-1256");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but I didn't see what expected expression.
I wrote some codes in C# for this purpose ,like this

```
int index = 0;
while (response[index] != 0x00)
    result = result + Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256").GetString(response, index++, 1);
```

it works fine.

does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `input`?

Comment: Please try to post comp!ete code so we can test with it.

Comment: @greenapps input is  "A0C8E5CFC7CF2DC7DDDEE5ED"

Comment: I asked for the type. You told me the content. Then put complete code in your post.

Comment: @greenapps It's updated

Comment: `String input = "A0C8E5CFC7CF2DC7DDDEE5ED";`. That is not a 1256 encoded string to begin with. Strings in java are utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

First you convert your hex string into byte array. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java) post.

Then, convert the byte array byte[] into UTF-8 using

```
String str = new String(byte[], "windows-1256");
```

UTF-8 is the native android encoding. Hope it helps.